# SQL bestsellers query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with finding bestselling books in each category. With attached code I can find only categories of needed books but how to find this books?

```
SELECT b.category_id, max(b.total_quantity) as max_quantity
    FROM (
      SELECT books.id, books.category_id, sum(order_items.quantity) as total_quantity
      FROM order_items 
        INNER JOIN orders ON order_items.order_id = orders.id
        INNER JOIN books on order_items.book_id = books.id
      WHERE orders.status in (2, 3)
      GROUP BY books.id
    ) as b
    GROUP BY b.category_id
```

Comment: You can join the product table with the results of this query.

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.id), b.*, SUM(oi.quantity) as total_quantity
FROM order_items oi JOIN
     orders o
     ON oi.order_id = o.id JOIN
     books b
     ON oi.book_id = b.id
WHERE o.status in (2, 3)
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY b.category_id, total_quantity DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter in the `having` clause with a correlated, aggregate query that returns the top selling quantity for the related category:

```
select b.id, b.category_id, sum(oi.quantity) as total_quantity
from order_items oi
inner join orders o on oi.order_id = o.id and o.status in (2, 3)
inner join books b on oi.book_id = b.id
having sum(oi.quantity) = (
    select sum(oi.quantity) 
    from order_items oi1
    inner join orders o1 on oi1.order_id = o1.id and o1.status in (2, 3)
    inner join books b1 on oi1.book_id = b1.id
    where b1.category_id = b.category_id
    group by b1.id
    order by sum(oi.quantity) desc
    limit 1
)
group by b.id, b.category_id
```

Or, if your RDBMS supports window functions (and allows mixing them with aggregation):

```
select id, category_id, total_quantity
from (
    select 
        b.id, 
        b.category_id, 
        sum(oi.quantity) as total_quantity,
        rank() over(partition by b.category_id order by sum(oi.quantity) desc) rn
    from order_items oi
    inner join orders o on oi.order_id = o.id and o.status in (2, 3)
    inner join books b on oi.book_id = b.id
    group by b.id, b.category_id
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a DENSE_RANK over the SUM.
If available in the RDBMS.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
      SELECT books.id, books.category_id
      , SUM(orditm.quantity) AS total_quantity
      , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY books.category_id ORDER BY SUM(order_items.quantity) DESC) AS Rnk
      FROM order_items AS orditm
      JOIN orders ON orditm.order_id = orders.id
      JOIN books ON orditm.book_id = books.id
      WHERE orders.status IN (2, 3)
      GROUP BY books.id, books.category_id
) q
WHERE Rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must have book_name column in your books table. So you can try below query -

```
SELECT b.book_name, b.category_id, max(b.total_quantity) as max_quantity
    FROM (
      SELECT books.id, books.book_name, books.category_id, sum(order_items.quantity) as total_quantity
      FROM order_items 
        INNER JOIN orders ON order_items.order_id = orders.id
        INNER JOIN books on order_items.book_id = books.id
      WHERE orders.status in (2, 3)
      GROUP BY books.id
    ) as b
    GROUP BY b.category_id
```